# Qt Creator crashes when trying to run an OpenCV program. [ntdll.dll crash]

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opencv, memory-leaks

I have QT Creator 3.2.2 for windows. I am using mingw-x64 with gcc/g++ - 4.9.1 as my compiler/debugger.
I used Cmake to build the libraries.

Currently, am trying to run this code  :

```
#include <core/cvstd.hpp>
#include <core/mat.hpp>
#include <core/types.hpp>
#include <core.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <highgui.hpp>
#include <imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <vector>
#include <video/background_segm.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Mat image = imread("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Random\\QtTrySimple\\Try\\bgm.jpeg");
  namedWindow("LOL");
  imshow("LOL", image);    
}
```

But the program crashes with a 'Critical error detected c0000374'. From what I understand this error indicates a memory leak on the heap.

Also, here is the stack when it crashes:

```
0   ntdll!RtlUnhandledExceptionFilter   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll       0x775b40d0  
1   ntdll!EtwEnumerateProcessRegGuids   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll       0x775b4746  
2   ntdll!RtlQueryProcessLockInformation    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll       0x775b5952  
3   ntdll!RtlLogStackBackTrace  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll       0x775b7604  
4   ntdll!RtlIsDosDeviceName_U  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll       0x7755dc47
```

I have no idea why the memory leak is happening. But am guessing it's something to do with OpenCV using windows API to show a display window.

EDIT : The image isn't empty. I am checking for an empty image in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the lack of information, I can only guess this is the obvious case of `cv::imread()` returning an empty `cv::Mat`. This happens when it fails to find/open the file:

```
Mat image = imread("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Random\\QtTrySimple\\Try\\bgm.jpeg");
if (image.empty())
{
    std::cout << "!!! Failed to open image" << std::endl;
    return -1;      
}

imshow("LOL", image);    
waitKey(0);
```

In this case, the crash happens because `imshow()` is invoked to display... nothing.

Don't forget to call `waitKey(0)` at the end, or the window will be closed immediately and you won't be able to see it.

Comment: The image isn't empty, that was the first thing that I tried when my program crashed. Plus if the image is empty and you still try to display it, OpenCV usually throws an assertion error.

Comment: Then it could be a problem with the libraries the application was linked with. But that's something I can't help you with (due to the lack of information). I'm pretty sure you can find the answer by searching on this site. There has been many similar questions around here.